# Wine pollutes "Open With" application list

Tags: wine

The dialog box in question here is the one you get with the context menu option "open with other applications". Wine seems to have inserted more than a dozen or so entries for each application I install, which makes it a pain to find the correct application:

[image]

What can I do to remove the duplicates?

---

**Update:** Neither of the two solutions really work. The bug is interesting, but the symptoms does not match my problem (I'm not having problem with uninstalling applications, but rather the things that are inserted after installing them), and with the other one, *all* references to the Wine application are removed, which actually makes the problem worse (although it may be an acceptable solution if nothing else can be found). So this is still an open question; any takers?

Comment: I think you should report this bug at Launchpad.net

Comment: The same Wine component (winemenubuilder) is responsible for both problems, the one at the launchpad bug and the one you're having.  A fix is in progress at winehq, but it was in part blocked by a bug in Ubuntu that I've now taken care of: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-utils/+bug/602799

Comment: @Yi Jang (intentionally misspelled so the SE won't remove it) are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 21):

Remove wine*.desktop files from ~/.local/share/applications and edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

If you're feeling lazy you can just run:

```
sed -i '/wine/d' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

and:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```

or all in one line:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine* ; sed -i '/wine/d' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Comment: Anyway to do this a program, I have about 100 duplicates

Comment: it could be done on the command line using `rm ~/.local/share/applications/*<insert most of the name of the duplicate here>.desktop`

Comment: Thanks. I had another (probably redundant) subdirectory "wine" in ~/.local/share/applications/, and after checking the file modif date of the *.desktop files in this dir  ~/.local/share/applications/wine, I decided to remove this directory and  all files inside. I suspect it came from an older ubuntu distri (now I'm on 12.04). After deleting, a lot of duplicates were gone. I was not able to remove them thru alacarte.

Comment: It works, but after doing this I seem to have lost the ability to open certain files with WINE programs by simply double clicking on them, which is kind of a pain...

Answer (score 9):

It's a known problem.  Here is the associated launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.2/+bug/420089

Unfortunately it's not an easy problem to fix in Wine (or Gnome), because there isn't a good way for figuring out when an application has been removed.

Comment: I should note that I have been having an ongoing discussion with the author of winemenubuilder about how to correctly solve this problem (as well as obsolete entries in the start menu)

Comment: I've seen success in getting menu entries removed, but the bug still persists in some ways.

Comment: It has a easy fix .

Answer (score 5):

Just found this post on webupd8: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/fix-open-with-menu-when-using-ms-office.html#more

Just right click the Ubuntu Menu Logo, select "edit menu" and remove unused entries  under "other".

Comment: This post was helpful. Although, in Ubuntu 11.04 you can't right-click on the menu, you have to either have to hit super (windows key) and type Main Menu, or run "alacarte" from command line.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_clean_the_Open_With_List.3F

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine*
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/*/application-x-wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/application/x-wine-extension*
```