# How to remove Open with menu items from Nautilus after Wine is deleted?

Tags: nautilus, wine

I installed Wine via the Software Center and later removed it. The problem is that I still have *Open with Notepad* and other right click menu items in Nautilus. I checked if anything from Wine remained in Synaptic, but I didn't see any packages installed. I'm using Natty.

Is there a way I can remove these menu items?

[image: Nautilus right click menu]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wine pollutes "Open With" application list](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5517/wine-pollutes-open-with-application-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the corresponding .desktop files from `~/.local/share/applications` where `~` is your home directory.

Comment: and restart nautilus