# How to remove Wine apps from context menu?

Tags: wine

I had installed Wine for emulating Photoshop CS5, but later I uninstalled it. However, it still displayed in the right click context menu.

How can I remove it from the context menu?

Comment: Related: [How to remove Open with menu items from Nautilus after Wine is deleted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62979/how-to-remove-open-with-menu-items-from-nautilus-after-wine-is-deleted)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run the below command in terminal

```
xdg-open ~/.local/share/applications
```

Look for wine related files like wine-extension-chm.desktop, wine-extension-txt.desktop, wine-extension-xml.desktop .... and delete them.

[image: How to get rid of wine programs in the right click context menu?]

Once thats done you should not be seeing any of the wine related programs on the right click context menu.